# What is "Береза" in "Повернулися із Берези, з-за Байкалу, із Соловків"?

Tags: значення-слів

From a poem by [Яр Славутич](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87_%D0%AF%D1%80):

> Нами снили поліські пущі,
>   Гайдамацькі яри в полях.
>   І прийшли ми до них, живущі,
>   Подолавши пекельний шлях.
>
> Повернулися із **Берези**,
>   З-за Байкалу, із Соловків,
>   Багатющі, неначе крези,
>   Гнівом часу, жалем віків.

What is **Береза**?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think that the word "Береза" here is the name of **the prizon camp "[Bereza Kartuska](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bereza_Kartuska_prison)"**. Also, we can see here the word "Соловки" ("із Соловків"), which is the name of [Solovki prison camp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solovki_prison_camp).

Comment: This answer seems very viable. However, to make it scientifically correct, one should probably find other uses of this word in this context.